# Split data from ethernet

Tags: c

I need split data from ethernet. Data is in this format:

```
ZMXXX,angle*CHCK
```

Where angle is number. For example: `ZMXXX,900*5A`

And I need separated `ZMXXX,900` and `5A`. I wrote this function:

```
void split_data(char analyze[])
{    
    char *words[5]; uint8_t i=0;
    words[i] = strtok(analyze,"*");

    while(words[i]!=NULL)
    {
        words[++i] = strtok(NULL,"*");
    }
}
```

And result is here:

[image: PICTURE]

And now, how I can get this data from variable:

```
words[0]
words[1]
```

Comment: Well, exactly like that; `words[0]`, `words[1]`, etc. What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: Where does the *ethernet* fit in?

Comment: @EdHeal : Possible that part is yet to come.

Comment: What do you mean 'get this data'?  You've correctly split the data.  You throw away your efforts in the sample code by returning immediately.  You can't return `words` from the function, but you could use it after the loop shown that splits it up.  Or you can redesign your function so that you pass in an array of pointers which are initialized/set by the function.  You'd return the number of fields found, though if the format is known and fixed, you know that the answer is 2.  You could therefore use `int split_data(char analyze[], char **words, int max_words)` for the signature.

Comment: I need split this data: `$ZMXXX,angle*CHCK<CR><LF>`
where: 
ZMXXX is command
angle is angle (900 = 90°)
CHCK = Check sum

For example: `$ZMXXX,900*5A<CR><LF>`

This data I receive from ethernet, delete $ and <CR><LF>. After this I have got data in this format: ZMXXX,900*5A

And I need to split this string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format you mention to be fixed, there is no need for the expensive and error-prone `strtok()`.

Use the good old [`strchr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strchr.html):

```
int parse(char * input, char ** output)
{
  int result = -1; /* Be pessimistic. */

  if ((NULL == inout) || (NULL == output))
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
    goto lblExit;
  }

  char * pc = strchr(analyze, '*');
  if (NULL == pc);
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
    goto lblExit;
  }

  *pc = '\0'; /* Set a temporary `0`-terminator. */
  output[0] = strdup(analyze); /* Copy the 1st token. */
  if (NULL == output[0])
  {
    goto lblExit;
  }

  *pc = '*'; /* Restore the original. */

  output[1] = strdup(pc + 1); /* Seek beyond the `*` and copy the 2nd token. */
  if (NULL == output[1])
  {
    free(outout[0]); /** Clean up. */
    goto lblExit;
  }

  result = 0; /* Indicate success. */

lblExit:

  return result;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L /* To make strdup() available. */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int parse(char *, char **);

int main(void)
{
   char data[] = "ZMXXX,900*5A";
   char * words[2];

   if (-1 == parse(data, words))
   {
     perror("parse() failed");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("word 1 = '%s'\n", words[0]);
   printf("word 2 = '%s'\n", words[1]);

   free(words[0]);
   free(words[1]);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The above code is expected to print:

```
word 1 = 'ZMXXX,900'
word 2 = '5A'
```

Note that [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) isn't Standard C, but POSIX. It might need to be activated using one of the appropriate defines.